# ping 100% packet loss - can't ping to server

Tags: linux, port, ping, socket

when I try to ping my newly created server it shows:

```
vasanth@vasanth-client:~$ ping -c 4 server.ip.name
PING server.ip.name (server.ip.address ) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- server.ip.name ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3055ms
```

when I check ICMP is allowed it shows:

```
[root@vasanth-server ~]$ firewall-cmd --query-icmp-block=echo-request
no
```

firewall zone status:

```
[root@vasanth-server ~]$ firewall-cmd --list-all-zones
....
....

public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens192
  sources: 
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client http https ssh
  ports: 3306/tcp 33060/tcp 8082/tcp 6666/tcp 7777/tcp 4444/tcp 12345/tcp
  protocols: 
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

....
....
```

can somebody explain why I can't ping my server?

Comment: Assuming that your server is indeed online either the server itself blocks pings (firewall, `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all` kernel sysctl tunable) or something along the path (your firewall, provider firewall or similar cloud providers security groups) blocks ping/ICMP echo reply requests.

Answer (score 0):

*Hey, can you ping from the server to another domain like google.com?*
*If not, please double-check your network settings.*
**Check lists:**

- **Your IP and gateway must have a valid subnet mask in the nmtui
  settings or any other tool or configuration file you use.**

**Alternatively, use the following commands to enable ICMP:**

- iptables -A {INPUT|OUTPUT} -p icmp -j {ACCEPT|REJECT|DROP}
- iptables -A {INPUT|OUTPUT} -p icmp --icmp-type {0|8}  -j
  {ACCEPT|REJECT|DROP}
- iptables -A {INPUT|OUTPUT} -p icmp --icmp-type
  {echo-reply|echo-request} -j {ACCEPT|REJECT|DROP}
- iptables -A {INPUT|OUTPUT} -p icmp --icmp-type
  {echo-reply|echo-request} -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j
  {ACCEPT|REJECT|DROP}

**Note:** *Make sure you check your internet connection of server or your device. If it is VM check your network adapter setting (VMWare/OracleVB) or Virtual switch (Hyper-V)*

Comment: Hi @Masab Bin Zahid Yes I can ping from the server to another domain like google.

Comment: Then its your firewall issue. allow icmp or try to telnet any port which is open. You can scan network using nmap to check if ports are allowing any connection.